# VBA change parameters of for loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop

I am trying to create a count which runs through a column checks if the value is in between the designated criteria than tallies it (that works).

But I am trying to nest it in another for loop, so once it finishes the first category

```
x=4
y=13
So For a= x To y
Runs Code

then i want it to run

For a = 14 To 27
code code code

x= x+14
y= y+14

For a = 28 to 41 
etc....
```

---

**Here is my code**

```
    Sub count()

    Dim c, d As Long
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer

    c = 0
    d = 0
    x = 4
    y = 13

    lr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Probability").Cells(Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    For a = x To y
        For b = 2 To lr
            If Cells(b, 2) >= Cells(a, 10) Then
                c = c + 1
            End If
            If Cells(b, 2) >= Cells(a, 11) Then
                d = d + 1
            End If
            Range("L" & a).Value = c
            Range("M" & a).Value = d
        Next b
        c = 0
        d = 0

        x = x + 14
        y = y + 14
        Range("O1").Value = x
        Range("P1").Value = y
    Next a
    End Sub
```

Comment: For Loop doesn't work that way. Even if you change x inside it, a will still have the first value of x which is 4. Now how do you want to increment a, it is not clear. At first instance you assign it 4, then 14 and then 28? If you are to stick with +14 interval, wouldn't it be 4, 18, 32? Or am I missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-read your question and you might just be missing another loop as below.

```
Do
    For a = x To y
        For b = 2 To lr
            If Cells(b, 2) >= Cells(a, 10) Then c = c + 1
            If Cells(b, 2) >= Cells(a, 11) Then d = d + 1
            Range("L" & a).Value = c
            Range("M" & a).Value = d
        Next b
        c = 0
        d = 0
    Next a
    x = x + 14
    y = y + 14
    Range("O1").Value = x
    Range("P1").Value = y
Loop Until "Set condition here"
```

I however I still misunderstood your question, comment out clarifications.

Comment: Thanks! I got it to work, inserted a while loop in the beginning!